# I got the new iPad Air for Christmas. Everything transferred seamlessly but one app. What now?

Tags: applications, restore, ipad

It was the game Tribez. The information was last backed up on my old iPad 2 11/18/13. I don't understand how all of my other apps were brought over perfectly, but this one. I have contacted their customer service and they said to do another back up on the old one, then restore my new one again. That would mean I need to do a backup of the new first. Do the backups cancel each other out? Keeping only one?

Comment: Are you backing up to a PC or a Mac or iCloud? Each has different options for when backups over-write each other as well as strategies to keep a new backup from clobbering an old one. Also, if you have a spare iOS device to hold an old backup or test, you might be able to work around limitations on backup times and storage.

Comment: PC. I understand what you say, just feel like I'm going to blow it trying. It's a stupid game. Maybe I should just start it over!

Comment: Perfect - on a PC you can look in the folders listed to make a copy of the old backup to be sure you don't overwrite things. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4946 You are correct, that it's a bit of fuss just to try again at the restore.

Answer (score 1):

You can backup data from apps with a program such as [PhoneView](https://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) (Mac) or [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) (Mac & Windows).

> Browse, manage and download most any data saved by App Store apps from your iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch. If you're looking for a quick way to download saved recordings, videos or images from your apps, this is it. Even transfer game high scores between devices. *--PhoneView*

Once you have the app data, it can be restored to a new copy of the app downloaded from the App Store.